# Changing pixel value in Java

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage

I have a working test program that broadly does the following:

1. Read in an image file using `BufferedImage`
2. Bit Shift values into appropriate arrays
3. Re-bit shift values into integers
4. Write the values back out as an image file.

This works perfectly.

I am trying to change pixel values in between reading and writing the image file. (In this case, I am trying to change the first value in the red components. I am using a test printer to print out the values to view the changes. 
It shows that its changed, but when reading the new image again (with the value changed), the value is unchanged?

Below is the code (It compiles and runs) - Just need to uncomment the line to change the pixel value, and then when reading in the new altered image, comment out the line again to understand my problem.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JPEGtester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] RGBarray = null;
      int w = 0;
      int h = 0;

      //Declare color arrays
      int [][] alphaPixels = null;
      int [][] redPixels = null;
      int [][] greenPixels = null;
      int [][] bluePixels =null;

      BufferedImage imgBuf =null;
      try
      { 
         //Read image file -- (WHEN VALUE IS CHANGED, CHANGE THE IMAGE NAME TO new-test.jpg)
         imgBuf = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));

         //Get width and hieght of image
         w = imgBuf.getWidth();
         h = imgBuf.getHeight();

         RGBarray = imgBuf.getRGB(0,0,w,h,null,0,w);

         alphaPixels = new int [h][w];
         redPixels = new int [h][w];
         greenPixels = new int [h][w];
         bluePixels = new int [h][w];

         //Bit shift values into arrays
         int i=0;
         for(int row=0; row<h; row++)
         {
            for(int col=0; col<w; col++)
            {
               alphaPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[i]>>24)&0xff);
               redPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[i]>>16)&0xff);
               greenPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[i]>>8)&0xff);
               bluePixels[row][col] = (RGBarray[i]&0xff);
               i++;
            }
         }

         //THIS IS TRYING TO CHANGE THE FIRST VALUE OF THE RED PIXEL IN THE ARRAY BY ADDING 1
         //UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO CHANGE VALUES, AND THEN WILL PRINT OUT THE CHANGES VALUE IN THE TEST PRINTED ARRAY
         //THEN COMMENT THE LINE AND RE-RUN WITH THE NEW IMAGE. IT REMAINS UNCHANGED ?? (AS IF NEVER BEEN CHANGED)
         //redPixels[0][0] = redPixels[0][0]+1;

         //Test print the first 64 values of the Red Array
         for(int row=0; row<8; row++)
         {
            for(int col=0; col<8; col++)
            {
               System.out.print(redPixels[row][col]);
            }
         }

         //Set the values back to integers using re-bit shifting
         for(int row=0; row<h; row++)
         {
            for(int col=0; col<w; col++)
            {
               int rgb = (alphaPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 24 | (redPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 16 | (greenPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 8 | (bluePixels[row][col] & 0xff);
               imgBuf.setRGB(col, row, rgb);
            }
         }

         //Write back image
         ImageIO.write(imgBuf, "jpg", new File("new-test.jpg"));
      }
      catch(IOException i)
      {};
   }
}
```

Comment: You know that JPGs are lossy and thus a single slightly brighter pixel might result in the same compressed value as the unchanged version, don't you? Did you try with more substantial changes?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the compression. In fact I did change the value by adding 50 to the pixel value, and the whole array set changed completely ? I'm not sure why this occurs, it doesn't change when the value is added by 1, but when adding 50, changes all values (seemly) ?

Comment: have you tried writing it out in png, bmp, or some other lossless format?

Comment: Well JPG compression doesn't compress single pixels but larger blocks and thus if you change one pixel dramatically that _might_ influence all other pixels in the same block. Maybe you'd want to use a non-compressing or losslessly compressing format for your tests to remove that source of confusion.

Comment: I just ran the program again using a .gif format, but the value is still unchanged? It must be to do with how I am writing the values out? Or maybe my bit shifting is incorrect? (despite getting a accurate image)

Answer (score 0):

As redPixels is a separate object, with values copied from RGBArray which is  copied from the buffered image itself, a first step would be:

```
RGBArray[0] = redPixels[0][0] + 1;

imgBuf.setRGB(0,0,w,h,RGBArray,0,w);
```

Because of the lossy compression `+ 1` might not be a sufficient change to effect a different value. `+ 10` or also changing adjacent pixels might help.

Of course:

```
RGBArray[row * w + col] = ...[row][col];
```

---

Or work with the `setRGB` version for setting single pixels:

```
     for (int row = 0; row < h; row++)
     {
         for (int col = 0; col < w; col++)
         {
             int c = (alphaPixels[row][col] << 24)
                     | (redPixels[row][col] << 16)
                     | (greenPixels[row][col] << 8)
                     | (bluePixels[row][col]);
             imgBuf.setRGB(row, col, c);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not using RGBArray array after bit shifting into the arrays. I simply use those red, green and blues array to write back to the image. How can I use that alteration to my program? Thanks

Comment: Extended the answer with an immediate usage. If you are interested im more efficiency, you might consider WritableRaster and http://www.cs.tut.fi/lintula/manual/java/tutorial/2d/images/filtering.html and [ColorConvertOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html),